# Extract JSON Data From ThingSpeak API

Tags: html, json

so i want to get the value from one oof my fields in my thingspeak, i'm able to extract data from my channels but i want to get only one specific field

i read the documentation and the api link that looks like this

```
https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/<channel_id>/feeds.json?results=1
```

and when i opened the link it showed this

```
{"channel":{"id":1688112,"name":"ESP8266 - Web Controlled LED","latitude":"0.0","longitude":"0.0","field1":"Command","field2":"Red LED","field3":"Green LED","field4":"Blue Led","created_at":"2022-03-29T00:36:06Z","updated_at":"2022-04-06T03:12:36Z","last_entry_id":443},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2022-04-10T07:06:01Z","entry_id":443,"field1":null,"field2":"0","field3":"0","field4":"0"}]}
```

so my question is how do i extract the data for example from my field2 data where "field2":"0"?

i want to use it for my project in my html where later it can do some functions in my content.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the program you use.
But usually you find a JSON library to be installed in your IDE.
With it you extract any field from the JSON file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).